# invalid narrowing conversion from (int) to (short) error

Tags: c++, type-conversion, type-narrowing

I am getting an error with both (short)m_nScreen.

This is code to create a console window, and whenever I try and run it, I get errors. The error I get is "invalid narrowing conversion from (int) to (short)"

```
        m_rectWindow = { 0, 0, (short)m_nScreenWidth - 1, (short)m_nScreenHeight - 1 };
```

Comment: No images of plain text please!!

Comment: my bad, im still learning the ropes of stack overflow lol

Comment: So post the error text formatted properly please (usually as code markup gives most readable results). Also a [mcve] with the minimum of code to reproduce these errors.

Comment: okay, i just left the code that would produce the errors. is that better?

Comment: No, that's not an [mcve], read that link thoroughly again.

Comment: i added in the error, which is "invalid narrowing conversion from (int) to (short)"

Comment: Maybe you posted the wrong picture.

Comment: yeah i did, thats my mistake

Comment: change to `(short)(m_nScreenWidth - 1)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

`(short)m_nScreenHeight - 1` narrows `m_nScreenHeight` only to widen it again prior to the subtraction with 1, which is an `int`- thus an useless narrowing. [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70796101/invalid-narrowing-conversion-from-int-to-short-error#comment125157194_70796101).

Instead, subtract and then narrow the difference.

```
// (short)m_nScreenHeight - 1
(short)(m_nScreenHeight - 1)
```

Same for `m_nScreenWidth`.